# Uninstalling gems installed by me from default and global gemsets

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have installed a lot of gems in the default and global gemsets by mistake. I want to remove all gems that were installed in those gemsets by me. Is there a way do to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RVM and want to remove all the gems installed there, you can use

`rvm gemset empty <gemset>`

This will basically remove all gems from the gemset you specify, then you'll have a blank slate to start over installing things that you only care about.